# Collect directory structure and file names from server, not file contents

Tags: python, rsync, paramiko, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to create a python3 app to store file backups on a remote server.  Using rsync to sync between my local and remote machine works fine.

What I would like to achieve is a json file containing the server directory structure and file names, not the content of the files, only names, and store the structure as a json file to be returned to my python app.

I have tried using rsync commands to achieve this, but I keep copying complete files, I only need the directory names, and file names contained within the server, ideally I would like to be stored as a json file so I can convert to dict in my program.

My server runs ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through folders in your app recursively and create a tree structure. [Here is how to get the content of a directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/1771375)

Hope this helps!